# number theory: Let $m>n$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, prove if $k$ divides $m$ and $k$ divides $n$ then $k$ divides $m\bmod{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $m>n$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, prove if  $k$ divides $m$ and $k$ divides $n$ then $k$ divides $m\bmod{n}$.

How should I approach this question? 
I only got $m=qk$ and $n=pk$ if $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{q}{p}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $\,\ ak\ {\rm mod}\,\ bk\, =\, ak - q(bk)\, =\, (a\!-\!qb) k$

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know how to prove it now.

Comment: Nice to see some "key ideas" at work! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you express $m$ in terms of $n$ and $m$ (mod $n$)?

What would happen if $k$ didn't divide $m$ (mod $n$)?

Answer (score 0):

Write $m>n$ in the form $m=qn+r$, where $q$ is the quotient and $r \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ is the remainder obtained when we divide $m$ by $n$.  Thus $r$ is the quantity $m~\operatorname{mod}~n$. Since $k$ divides $m$ and $n$, $k$ also divides $m-qn$, hence $k$ divides $r$.